# Add sequence number to file name

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a requirement to add a sequence number to file names in sequential order and reset the value to 1 on next run.

Job is scheduled to run once every hour. I could see we can achieve incrementing the value using getStatevalue but not sure how can we reset the value. Could you please help me.

Thanks,

Kumar

Comment: So you want to count flowfiles coming from smth like  listfile processor?

Comment: add more info to your question ! like what have you done so far ? or you are stuck where, else dagget comment is your answer